# How to get unique value in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

**My Query:**

```
select unique f.documentname,f.projectname,f.documentdescription,
f.P0BUSINESSUNIT,f.P0ZONENAME,f.P0REGIONNAME,f.P0GROUPNAME,l.processname,
f.ORIGINALCREATIONDATE 
from p0findoc f, lcstep@sdrcpadm l 
where f.inlifecyclename IS Not Null and 
f.INLIFECYCLESTEP in (select l.LIFECYCLESTEP  from lcstep@sdrcpadm ) and ORIGINALCREATIONDATE > '2021/01/01' 
order by f.P0BUSINESSUNIT,f.P0ZONENAME,f.P0REGIONNAME,f.P0GROUPNAME ;
```

**Output:**

```
DocumentName, Project Name, Doc Description...so on

PD71017 311503  Change Order 1  CIS Americas CIS    Brazil CIS  Not Applicable  Deliver Services    2021/05/04-14:50:07:998

PD71017 311503  Change Order 1  CIS Americas CIS    Brazil CIS  Not Applicable  Notification    2021/05/04-14:50:07:998

PD71017 311503  Change Order 1  CIS Americas CIS    Brazil CIS  Not Applicable  PRJ Notification    2021/05/04-14:50:07:998

PD71017 311503  Change Order 1  CIS Americas CIS    Brazil CIS  Not Applicable  Request CSS Closure 2021/05/04-14:50:07:998

PD71017 311503  Change Order 1  CIS Americas CIS    Brazil CIS  Not Applicable  Validation Failure  2021/05/04-14:50:07:998

PD73834 311503  Change Order 4  CIS Americas CIS    Brazil CIS  Not Applicable  Deliver Services    2021/09/13-17:24:18:433

PD73834 311503  Change Order 4  CIS Americas CIS    Brazil CIS  Not Applicable  Notification    2021/09/13-17:24:18:433
```

**Here in above output i want to have unique value only for column 'document name' that is PDxxxx. there are multiple values for column process name so wanted to have just one.**

Comment: Please use modern join syntax, instead of the comma-separated list of tables (from the 80s).

Comment: "..i want to have unique value only for column 'document name'.." -- What do you want in case there are multiple matches `lcstep@sdrcpadm`? Retrive a random row, added them together, other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want one (*any*) process name, then take e.g. "first" or "last" (min or max), but you'll have to aggregate on all other columns (which also means that you don't need `unique` any more):

```
  SELECT f.documentname,
         f.projectname,
         f.documentdescription,
         f.p0businessunit,
         f.p0zonename,
         f.p0regionname,
         f.p0groupname,
         MAX (l.processname) processname,
         f.originalcreationdate
    FROM p0findoc f
         JOIN lcstep@sdrcpadm l ON f.inlifecyclestep = l.lifecyclestep
   WHERE     f.inlifecyclename IS NOT NULL
         AND originalcreationdate > DATE '2021-01-01'
GROUP BY f.documentname,
         f.projectname,
         f.documentdescription,
         f.p0businessunit,
         f.p0zonename,
         f.p0regionname,
         f.p0groupname,
         f.originalcreationdate
ORDER BY f.p0businessunit,
         f.p0zonename,
         f.p0regionname,
         f.p0groupname;
```

Also, you'd rather not compare dates to strings; that's why I used date literal in `where` clause. Finally, switched to `JOIN`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're getting the wrong answer because you did not join your two tables together with any kind of a unique key.

Change your FROM clause to `From p0findoc f Inner Join lcstep@sdrcpadm l on f.InLifecycleStep=l.LifecycleStep`

and remove the subquery   `f.INLIFECYCLESTEP in (select l.LIFECYCLESTEP  from lcstep@sdrcpadm )`